# Timezone issue importing ICS file into Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2016, time-zone, icloud

When a meeting invitation is generated in iCloud Calendar and sent to me, I have to import the .ics file into Outlook 2016.  When I do so, it imports 1 hour off.

- iCloud timezone is set to 'United Kingdom Time'.
- Event created at 7.30pm with timezone as 'United Kingdom Time', as per next screenshot:
  [Event being created in iCloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/je7XS.png)
- PC is set to London time, with Daylight Savings Hours enabled
- When imported into Outlook, the time is now 8.30pm, as you can see here:
  [Outlook showing wrong time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z78uu.png)
- The .ics file has 'TZID:Europe/London'

Any idea how I can get Outlook to import it at 7.30pm without changing everything to UTC?  My clients won't change to UTC.

Thanks

Comment: (1) What is “United Kingdom Time”? Is it UTC, or is it UTC+DST?  (2) Why do you have three things highlighted in your second image, *including material that you’ve redacted,* and not the part that shows the event ***beginning*** at 8:30?  (3) You have obviously made an attempt to redact some information, but note that your second image still shows what appears to be somebody’s real name.

Comment: UK time is currently British Summer Time (BST) which is +1 GMT.  GMT is the same as UTC.  On the second image (point 2), the three things highlighted are the iCloud event showing the start time or 7.30pm, my PC's timezone as UTC + 1 and the Outlook event showing a start time of 20.30 (see beneath the text "Required. Please Respond"). The Outlook event should show a start time of 7.30pm.  Thanks.

Comment: You may have a look at this: https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/calendar/meeting-requests-and-appointments-are-off-by-one-hour/. Hope this could provide some insight.

Answer (score 2):

Faced some similar issue.  Basically it depends whether ICS is specifying UTC or local time. For e.g   consider the name value pair.

DTEND:20200702T091500Z

The above name value pair specifies  UTC (the trailing "Z" specifies that time is UTC). So your calendar will treat this as 9:15 AM in UTC, and after importing show it based on your local calendar (as in the time zone you have used)

To make ics specify local time rather than UTC time you will have to remove the last trailing "Z" and specify as

DTEND:20200702T091500

Similar change needs to be done to  DSTART

https://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/dateTime.html